# Position widget in stack with percent

Tags: dart, flutter

Let's say I want to position a widget inside a `Stack` but with a percent of the Stack position instead of a fixed size. How to do that in flutter ?

I'd expect that the `Positionned.fromRelativeRect` constructor would be the thing, using floats between 0 and 1. But seems like no.

`Align` allows to position the widget in percent. But `heightFactor` and `widthFactor` changes the `Align` size instead of the child size. Which is not what I want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can combine a `Positioned.fill` and `LayoutBuilder` to achieve such result.

```
    new Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Positioned.fill(
        child: new LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: constraints.biggest.height * .59, bottom: constraints.biggest.height * .31),
              child: new Text("toto", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            );
          },
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 16):

use `FractionalOffset` & `FractionallySizedBox` it's very simple in contrast

- around no unnecessary code like `Positioned.fill`
- no no extra calculations like `Alignment`

```dart
...
 Container(
   color: Colors.blue[200],
   alignment: FractionalOffset(0.7, 0.6),
   child: FractionallySizedBox(
     widthFactor: 0.1,
     heightFactor: 1/3,
     child: Container(color: Colors.red[900])
   ),
 ),
...
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer, it makes it very easy to relatively position a relative size container in a variable screen size. Like a percentage width / height sized and placed div on the web.

Comment: Note that you have to put the alignment on the *parent* of the item you want to align.

Answer (score 13):

one thing that i figured out not long ago is that you can position a widget on the screen using a container its alignment parameter with the help of the `Alignment.lerp(x,y,z)` function

```dart
//the widget will be placed in the center of the container
alignment: Alignment.lerp(Alignment.topCenter, Alignment.bottomCenter, 0), 

//the widget will be placed in the bottom of the container
alignment: Alignment.lerp(Alignment.topCenter, Alignment.bottomCenter, 1), 

//the widget will be placed in the bottom quarter of the container
alignment: Alignment.lerp(Alignment.topCenter, Alignment.bottomCenter, 0.5), 

//the widget will be placed in the top quarter of the container
alignment: Alignment.lerp(Alignment.topCenter, Alignment.bottomCenter, -0.5),
```

Comment: You can use just `Alignment(-1.0 + x * 2, -1.0 + y * 2)` where `x` and `y` percentage by x and y

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `LayoutBuilder` then do without `Positioned.fill`, like this:
you need one `LayoutBuilder`, no need to turn around every elements and use `Transform.translate` instead of `Padding`.

```dart
  new LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(
              constraints.biggest.width * left,
              constraints.biggest.height * top),         
            child: new Text("toto", textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
          ),
          ...
        ],
      );
    }
  )
```