# How do i set the position of picture/button/text to be responsive for other device?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I try to set the position of picture/button/text by define the number but when my code run to others device my UI is not the same as runing on my device. This is the picture that show the result on my device and othe devide.

[my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhB1Q.jpg)

[others device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ir2r.jpg)

So, I try to use this code to make my code to be responsive.

```
 Container(
   child: Positioned(
      left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.4,
      top:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.28,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
             image: AssetImage("assets/images/LG5.png"))),
  ))),
```

And for setting the position of button and login TextFiled I use this code

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 80.0, right: 80.0, top: 300),
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    TextField(
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  borderSide:
                      BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.indigo[700]),
                ),
                labelText: 'Password',
              ),
            ),
    TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  borderSide:
                      BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.indigo[700]),
                ),
                labelText: 'Username',
              ),
            ),
Container(
  width: 300,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
    child: RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Login',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                color: Colors.indigo[700],
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
                }),
  )
```

for the above code I use this code to set position of TextFiled

```
margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 80.0, right: 80.0, top: 300)
```

for button for login is

```
margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40)
```

As you see, i define the number for the position and i try to use this code and assign to the left,right,top of "EdgeInsets.only" but it doesn't work.

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width 
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
```

So, how can i define the value of left,right,top with "EdgeInsets.only" and no need to fix the number and it will reponsive to other device?

Or, you can suggest me to do another way that more proper than this way because i'm not sure that i do the right way. I just learn Flutter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using absolute values like 20, 30 or whatsoever, try to use %. This way your UI will be responsive

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't know how to use % with 'EdgeInsets.only' function.

Comment: This might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637197/position-widget-in-stack-with-percent